# understanding how functions interact. How do i exit?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, call

My first question here, and my first bigger program.
ive stripped the program down however, so it just handles the question i have:

how does functions interact? i don't understand how to exit main() when i've gone through the other functions. Follow the code and you'll understand what i mean

```
def main():
    input("main root")
    while 1:
        try:             
            choice = int(input("choose 1 for second call, then follow to main and choose 4 to exit program "))
            if choice == 1:
                secondCall()
            if choice == 4:
                print("Program Exit (or it should anyway)!\n")
                break
        except:
            input("main except, and i dont wan't to get here either")
            ValueError
            KeyboardInterrupt
    input("main end, outside while-loop, \nwhy won't program ALWAYS end directly after this?")

def secondCall():
    input("second call root")
    myStacks = int(input("gimme a number: "))
    if myStacks <= 0:
        print("\nVälj minst en hög.\nBörja om!\n")
        secondCall()
    else:     
        while 1:
            myCards = int(input("one more number: ((i don't want to get back here when trying to exit program! a valueError here gets me back to main's except))"))
            input("calling on third")
            thirdCall(myStacks, myCards)

def thirdCall(arg1, arg2):
    print("third Call root, then calling on main(), but wont be able to exit the program right away when choosing 4 in main")
    input()
    main()

input("calling main")
main()
```

Comment: when do you want to exit main and under what condition?

Comment: What are those random exception names doing inside the except block?

Comment: once you remove the `input("main end, outside while-loop, \nwhy won't program ALWAYS end directly after this?"` your code will exit on pressing 4, as Daniel Roseman has said  `ValueError` and `KeyboardInterrupt` are doing nothing where they are

Comment: I want to exit after going through all the functions. After the choice ==1 in main, that sends me to secondCall, and later to thirdCall, i want to exit. but it sends me back first to thirdcall and back again to secondcall and again ask for an input (one more number). i thought that if i'm outside the while-loop in main, nothing more should happen?

Comment: you call secondCall and thirdCall where thirdCall calls main

Comment: main is actually a mainMenu, i want it to to ask for a correct value until it gets one, that's why i have the exceptions... and it doesn't exit even if I remove the input, valueError and KbdInterrupt - or do you mean remove the whole Try-except-block?

Comment: Padraic Cunningham, what do you mean? i shouldn't call main in thirdCall?

Comment: you are looping in your code so it is not surprising that you end up back in main. If you want to stay in blocks until you get correct input use while loops and try/except blocks.

Comment: i do want to get back to main, but when i do, i want to be able to exit right away. But it doesn't work like that? it always goes back from where it came, that is: back to third, back to second and THEN to main, first now being able to exit? is that how it works?

Comment: once I end up back in main I can exit pressing 4.

Comment: ooooh i think i get it. Without calling main() in thirdCall, putting a break after line: thirdCall(myStacks, myCards) in secondCall, i get back to main directly and can exit it right away. It worked. Thank you!! i've spent hours on this! :)

Comment: no worries, your except should look something like `except ValueError:` put your exceptions inside not under

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have mutual recursion - "main" calls "third_call" which then calls "main" again.

I think your confusion may come from that when "main" is called from "third_call", it doesn't go back to "main", it starts "main" again, from the start, with a whole new set of variables, and starts another while loop.

When that 2nd "main" exits, and then the "third_call" completes, it then goes back to where "third_call" was called initially - i.e. in the while loop in "second_call" - and this loop is infinite - with no way out.

Since I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do - it is not easy to fix your code, but until you understand recurssion (i.e. functions calling themselves, or in your case function A, calling Func B, calling func C, which calls func A), you should use it with caution..

You also have recursion in "second_call" where you call "second_call" again - this will form a potentially infinte loop - and again I am not sure this is what you want: there are better ways to prompt the users again for input (i.e. use a loop, and not recurrsion).